# Push notifications for iOS web app by using sockets?

Tags: ios, web-applications, websocket

i wonder if the following scenario is possible:

is it possible to use web-sockets (e.g. socket.io) to implement a kind of push notification? i think about the following method: when i save a web-app to the homescreen, open it and close it (so it's in the background), i send a notification over a server and the web-app in the background displays a alert-view?

thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

Backgrounded app are not running. They will drop the connection after a few seconds.

The native notification system hands off the job of handling receiving notifications and restarting the app to the OS.

So you register to receive them with the OS and when one arrives to the device the OS will start your app and pass on the notification.

You'd need a PhoneGap native wrapper to achieve this for your web app.

[Example](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/06/09/phonegap-push/)

Comment: how app-store save are nativewrappers? any experience?

Comment: It seems to be a popular option and there are many high profile apps in the store. There's a listing of some at http://phonegap.com/apps/